# Why, in floating-point arithmetic, 0.9999999999999999 !=1 but 0.9999999999999999 + 1 == 2

Tags: python, floating-point, precision

I know this must be another floating-point accuracy issue:  Let x be 0.9999999999999999. Then x + 1 == 2 in floating-point arithmetic, but x != 1. What is happening? Below is what I have tried on my ipython console.

```
In [55]: x = 0.9999999999999999

In [56]: x==1
Out[56]: False

In [57]: x+1==2
Out[57]: True
```

[Edit] Existing questions about broken floating-point calculation are mostly about FP representation error,   which does not seem to be the main cause here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: see my edits. This is not a duplicate imho.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The floating-point format you are using has 53 bits in its significand. This means it can represent numbers as a 53-bit integer multiplied or divided by a power of two.

When `0.9999999999999999` is converted to this format, the closest representable value is (2<sup>53</sup>−1)/2<sup>53</sup>, which is exactly 0.99999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875. Note that the numerator uses exactly 53 bits.

When you add 1, the mathematical result would be (2<sup>54</sup>−1)/2<sup>53</sup>. The numerator would have 54 bits. This cannot be represented in the floating-point format, so it has to be rounded to fit. The two nearest representable values are:

- (2<sup>54</sup>−2)/2<sup>53</sup> = (2<sup>53</sup>−1)/2<sup>52</sup>, and
- (2<sup>54</sup>−0)/2<sup>53</sup> = 2.

These are both equally far away from the exact mathematically result. The rule for breaking ties is to use the value with a zero in the low bit of its significand. (Even though I have presented the significand as an integer here, it is a “left-adjusted” fraction in the floating-point format, so a numerator of 1 corresponds to the binary numeral 1.000000…000<sub>2</sub>.)

Thus, when 1 is added to `0.9999999999999999`, the computed result must be rounded to 2.

Answer (score 2):

In the interval from `0.5` to `1.0` you have one more bit for the fractional part, compared to the number of bits you have for the fractional part in the interval from `1.0` to `2.0`. So this is expected.

You can have another example with:

```
0.9999999999 + 1234567890.0
```

where there are ten figures `9` in the first addend.

A double-precision (i.e. 64 bits) (binary) floating-point type has a precision of approximately sixteen decimal digits. So a number can be remembered only from its "first" (i.e. most significant) circa sixteen figures.